# SAP S/4 HANA express edition を少ないメモリで動作させる方法

Tags: linux, vmware

調査などを目的として、SAP S/4 HANA の express edition を VMWare 仮想マシン上にインストールしました。

仮想マシンに 12GB のメモリを割り当てた状態では問題なく動作しているように見えますが、この割当を少なくすると webdispatcher などのサービスが起動しなくなります。

大量のデータ処理などは不要なので、少ないメモリ量で動作させたいと考えて global_allocation_limit などの値を変更しました。

いくつかのパラメータ値の変更をあわせ、5GB までは減らせることができましたが、可能な限り少なくしたいと考えています。

このような設定方法や、設定例など参考になる情報があれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ツールのインストール要件をよく確認してください。
少し調べた程度ですが、**最低でも 16GB は必要** なようです。(推奨は 24GB になっています)

参考:
[AWSで始めるSAP HANA, express edition ~バイナリーインストーラ版~ | SlideShare](https://www.slideshare.net/tkwhr/awssap-hana-express-edition)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。通常の運用に必要な環境が必要なわけではなく、簡単な操作ができる程度のものが欲しかったので、小さい仮想マシンでなんとかならないかな、と思って質問させていただいています。